# C# Windows Service runs but quits after the process has completed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have created a C# Windows Service and it does what it needs to do. Once it is completed the service stops.

What I need to happen is for the service to run with out stopping. This way when another feed of data is available the service will run through the source code and do what it needs to do.

Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance.

-Jeff

Comment: Without code we cant do much...

Comment: You've probably placed your code inside the `onstart` only. This event works as a trigger: it happens and your code must keep running after it, otherwise your service will stop. You can't place a forever loop inside it, because it must end to tell Windows your service is running properly. So, inside `OnStart`, you'll likely start a thread that will run forever (or based, on conditions, stop).

Comment: You're asking us to speculate on what you possibly could have done wrong. That's not how StackOverflow works. You need to describe the problem, post the relevant portion of your code, and ask a specific question about that code.

Answer (score 3):

The main function in a Windows Service must run inside of a loop, so that it will continue running until the receiving the Stop command. The kind of loop doesn't matter, but the service must continuously have work in order to keep running. In addition, the loop cannot be run in the OnStart method. Create a thread to run you're loop, and start the thread from the OnStart method.

Comment: Almost there: this loop can't be inside `OnStart`, or Windows will return "this service took too long to start".